# Any continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Not really sure how to proceed with this one. Can anyone help?

The question is:

> Show that any continuous map $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is constant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that any continuous integer-valued function of a real variable is constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236026/prove-that-any-continuous-integer-valued-function-of-a-real-variable-is-constant)

Comment: first restrict $f$ to [a,b]. If $f$ is continuous on [a,b] then $f$ us uniformly continuous thus for 1>m>0 there exist n such that $|f(x)-z|<m$ where $f(y)=z$ for $|x-y|<n$ where $m,n$ are real numbers choose sufficiently small n and m then $z-1<z-m<f(x)<z+m<z+1$ thus $f(x)$ must be $z$ unless contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the continuous map $f: X\to \mathbb{Z}$ is not constant. Then there exist $a,b\in X$ such that $f(a)<f(b)$. Let $A=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid n\leq f(a)\}$ and
$B=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid n > f(a)\}$. Both $A$ and $B$ are open sets,
$A\cup B=\mathbb{Z}$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
Therefore the preimage of each is open,
$f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)=X$ and
$f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset$.
Therefore the domain $X$ cannot be a connected space.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous, thus by the intermediate value theorem, $f(\mathbb{R})$ is an interval. If $f$ was not constant, $f(\mathbb{R})$ would contain at least two different values, let $x< y$ in $f(\mathbb{R})$, since $f(\mathbb{R})$ is an interval, $]x,y[\subset f(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathbb{Z}$ which is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the basic definition :
Say $f(c)=n$
Now choose $\epsilon <1$,  so there is a $\delta$ such that
$|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon <1$ which contradicts the fact that $|f(x)-f(c)|\geq 1$,  since $f(c), f(x)$ are both integers,  so unless they are equal,  the absolute difference must not be smaller than $1$.

Comment: Why can’t $f(x)=f(c)$ for $x$ close enough to $c$? i.e. why isn’t $f$ locally constant? (the answer is because $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, you’re using this implicitly)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be a real number. Note that $\{f(x)\}$ is a closed-open set in $\mathbb{Z}$. So $f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})$ must be a closed-open set of $\mathbb{R}$. Because it's not empty (it contains $x$) and $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, it follows that $f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})=\mathbb{R}$. $f$ is constant.

This only uses basic facts about connexity (the definition and $\mathbb{R}$ being connected) but if you want to go faster, you can just say that if $f$ is not constant, then $f(\mathbb{R})$ is a set containing at least two elements. It's not connected but continuous maps maintain connexity and $\mathbb{R}$ is. There's a contradiction.