# $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f\circ f = \exp$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, exponential-function, functional-equations

> Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f\circ f = \exp$? (We have no continuity hypothesis on $f$.)

This problem was given as an oral exam at the ENS (a school in France). I don't have the clues that the examiner might have given to the candidate.

I know a proof of this in the case where $f$ is continuous (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081/does-the-exponential-function-have-a-compositional-square-root).
I quote the proof here :

> $f(z)$ cannot take all values, for then so does $f(f(z))$, while $e^z$ omits zero.
> If $f(z)$ omits a value, that has to be zero, for $e^z$ takes all other values. Thus there is an entire function $h(z)$ such that $f(z) = e^{h(z)}$ (the complex plane is simply connected). Now
> $
> e^{h(e^{h(z)})} = e^z
> $
> and so $h(e^{h(z)}) = z + 2{\pi}ik$ for some fixed integer $k$. Since the right hand side takes all values, so does the left hand side. So $h(z)$ takes the two values $0$ and $2{\pi}i$, say $h(a) = 0$ and $h(b) = 2{\pi}i$.
> Now $a + 2{\pi}ik = h(e^{h(a)}) = h(e^0) = h(e^{2{\pi}i}) = h(e^{h(b)}) = b + 2{\pi}ik$
> and so $a = b$. Contradiction!

The problem is if we don't suppose $f$ is continuous, then we can't directly say $k$ is fixed. However the rest of the proof is still correct and seems a good way to start.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you mean a holomorphic (entire) function or an arbitrary function? –  Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/283500/42969, and the links in the comments.

Comment: See here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081/does-the-exponential-function-have-a-compositional-square-root

Comment: @VivaanDaga your link partially answers my question, but I don't follow why k is fixed in engelbrekt's answer. Moreover, I think it would be nice if we had an answer on math stackexchange too.

Comment: @MartinR : I edited my question. Maybe one could reopen it?

Comment: $(h(e^{h(z)}) - z)/(2 \pi i)$ is continuous and takes only integer values. It follows that it is constant, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236026/42969

Comment: @MartinR : why is this function continuous?

Comment: @math: The answer that you are referring to is about *holomorphic* functions satisfying $f(f(z)) = e^z$. Holomorphic functions are continuous. – That's why I asked in my first comment what kind of functions your question is about.

Comment: @MartinR : Ok sorry ! Actually I was looking for arbitrary function, with no continuity hypothesis.

Comment: In that case the discussion on MathOverflow is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: @MartinR : Thank you. What should I do ? Delete the part of my question with the mathoverflow answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124859/discussion-between-martin-r-and-math).